# Joining tables using a new alias column as the key

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql-workbench, amazon-redshift

When I try to join 2 tables with my data, I get an error that my reference is ambiguous or I get the order that my original table does not have the alias column.

This is among my first projects with sql and an important learning point for me so I appreciate the guidance.

Here is my code.

```
WITH 
RentDotComOnly AS
(
  SELECT 
    concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(clean_zip) AS "rent_count_clean_zip", 
    AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "rent_avg_price", 0.85*min(low_price) AS "rent_lower_bound", 1.15*max(high_price) AS "rent_upper_bound"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    source_type in (29,36,316) 
    AND week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
    AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
  GROUP BY monthlyzip
),
AllRJData AS
(
  SELECT
    concat(DATEPART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
    COUNT(clean_zip) AS "all_count_clean_zip", 
    AVG((low_price+high_price)/2) AS "all_avg_price"
  FROM 
    archived_apartments 
  WHERE 
    week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12' 
    AND is_house <> 1  
  GROUP BY monthlyzip
)
SELECT 
  concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip",
  COUNT(archived_apartments.clean_zip) as filtered_count_clean_zip, 
  RentDotComOnly.rent_count_clean_zip, RentDotComOnly.rent_avg_price, RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound, RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound,
  AllRjData.all_count_clean_zip, AllRjData.all_avg_price
FROM
archived_apartments 
JOIN AllRJData 
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = AllRJData.monthlyzip
JOIN RentDotComOnly
ON concat(DATE_PART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartments.clean_zip) = RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
WHERE 
  archived_apartments.week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12'
  AND archived_apartments.is_house <> 1 
  AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
  AND archived_apartments.low_price > RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound
  OR archived_apartments.high_price < RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound
  AND archived_apartments.week between '2015-07-06' and '2015-10-12'
  AND archived_apartments.is_house <> 1 
  AND archived_apartments.high_price <> 0 
GROUP BY monthlyzip
RentDotComOnly.rent_count_clean_zip, RentDotComOnly.rent_avg_price, RentDotComOnly.rent_lower_bound, RentDotComOnly.rent_upper_bound, 
AllRjData.all_count_clean_zip, AllRjData.all_avg_price
ORDER BY monthlyzip
```

Comment: Why `mysql-workbench` tag?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are really using.  Redshift doesn't support a function called `datepart()`  (there is a hyphen in the redshift name).

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The error is "[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column reference "monthlyzip" is ambiguous;" - I changed datepart() to date_part() and error persists.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `monthlyzip` column you are referring to in your join is ambiguous. You have three tables with that column, which table are you referring to?

If monthly_zip existed on `archived_apartments` you could do:

```
FROM
archived_apartments JOIN
AllRJData 
ON archived_apartments.monthlyzip = AllRJData.monthlyzip
JOIN RentDotComOnly 
ON archived_apartments.monthlyzip = RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
```

But it sounds like `monthly_zip` doesn't exist in `archived_apartments` so you can't actually join on that field. Instead you have to join on the formula you used to make `monthlyzip`:

```
FROM
archived_apartments JOIN
AllRJData 
ON concat(DATEPART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartment.clean_zip)  = AllRJData.monthlyzip
JOIN RentDotComOnly 
ON concat(DATEPART(mm,archived_apartments.week),archived_apartment.clean_zip)  = RentDotComOnly.monthlyzip
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment because this was also my logic. However, with this approach I get error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: column archived_apartments.monthlyzip does not exist;

Comment: Sounds like the column `monthlyzip` doesn't exist on `archived_apartments`. What column are you trying to join with here?

Comment: I'm trying to use a key I created that is not an existing column, note: 

concat(DATEPART(mm,archived_apartments.week),clean_zip) AS "monthlyzip

Comment: I get that, but we are talking about table `archived_apartments` in your `FROM`. That column doesn't exist in that table, so you can't use it as part of your join. You say `FROM archived_apartments JOIN AllRJData` but your `ON` doesn't refer to any column in your archived_apartments. If `archived_apartments` doesn't have a relationship to `AllRJData` then you can't join the two. Instead you have to join on the formula you used to make that column. I will update the answer with how that will work.

Comment: Thanks JNeville, I follow but I require grouping and summing based on date and zipcode thus my attempt was to create the key for all the tables. What's a solution here?

Comment: Updated the answer. I think that will do the trick for you. You pretty much have to create the key `monthly_zip` within the `ON` portion of your join. You could, alternately, make yet another CTE that doesn't aggregate, but rather just makes that column for the `archived_apartments` table and use that CTE instead of your `archived_apartments`. 6 of one, half a dozen of the other.

Comment: Thanks for your persistant effort with me. The syntax you used to use my formula does make sense to me but I am not sure that it is valid(?)...  I now get a different error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "RentDotComOnly"; - updated original code